# how to pass data through Intent from Java class which implements Filterable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, import, nullpointerexception

When passing data through an intent it shows an error.

```
appAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Activity activity = (Activity) context;

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("app_name", appInfo.getName());
            intent.putExtra("app_apk", appInfo.getAPK());
            intent.putExtra("app_version", appInfo.getVersion());
            intent.putExtra("app_source", appInfo.getSource());
            intent.putExtra("app_data", appInfo.getData());
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) appInfo.getIcon()).getBitmap();
            intent.putExtra("app_icon", bitmap);
            intent.putExtra("app_isSystem", appInfo.isSystem());

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                String transitionName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.transition_app_icon);

                ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, appIcon, transitionName);
                context.startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
            } else {
                context.startActivity(intent);
                activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.fade_back);
            }
        }
    });
```

Data not passing. Log cat showing that,  `Null pointer exception`.
But I don't know why.

Comment: Add Logcat here.

Comment: share  the error message

Comment: probable error would be that your appInfo object is null

Comment: remove context from context.startActivity()